# Gnuplot epslatex terminal not showing axis text

Tags: pdftex, gnuplot

The following minimal example shows how I make a plot using gnuplot to the "epslatex" terminal and want to include it in my document. However, the axis texsts do not show.. What might be wrong? Gnuplot makes a .tex file and an .eps file. I should have thought it was going to use both when converting to PDF. This is pdflatex by the way.

```
==GNUPLOT==
set format "$%g$"
set xlabel "Temperature $T_t$"
set ylabel "Difference $|f(s')-f(s)|$"
set xrange [0.1:20]
set yrange [1:20]
set zrange [0:1]
set terminal epslatex
set output "prob.eps"
splot exp(-y/x) title ""


==latex==
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{prob}
\end{document}
```

Comment: At the moment you're just including the EPS file, because you're using `\includegraphics`. You need to include the `.tex` file, which will in turn include the EPS. Try `\include{prob}` or `\input{prob}`.

Comment: Ah, right. This gives me _something_ but the placing of the labels is completely off!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `epslatex` terminal produces two files: A `.tex` file with the labels, and an `.eps` file with the graphical elements. The `.tex` file inserts the `.eps` file itself, so all you have to do is insert the `.tex` file using `\include` or `\input`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\input{prob}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Instead of trying to figure out how to correct the label placement, may I suggest you give PGFplots a try? It can create plots of many mathematical functions and of data within LaTeX, and if you need really complicated mathematics, it can use gnuplot as a back end. The advantage of PGFplots over the `epslatex` terminal is that it's much easier to adjust the appearance of the plots. Your plot could be created using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=10cm, height=6cm,
    domain=0.1:20, xmin=0,
    y domain=1:20,
    view={20}{50},
    xlabel=Temperature $T_t$,
    ylabel=Difference $|f(s')-f(s)|$,
    ylabel style={anchor=west},
    colormap/cool
]
\addplot3 [surf] {exp(-y/x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `pdflatex` will yield

[image]

Comment: Wow, thats really sweet! I need to look more into the manual. Can you tell me how I'd stretch the plot so its wider ratio wise?

Comment: For stretching the plot, you can set `width=<value>` and `height=<value>`. If you only set one of the two options, the plot will be scaled proportionally.

Comment: Okay, just a follow up. Ever since I put this plot in my document, it takes sooo long to compile. I am using the texstudio editor with its built-in pdf previewer, and it seems this previewer is trying to load the pdf like 6 times, and each time I get a dialog saying the source is not a valid pdf. Of couse, this is probably not latex related per se, but if it is because of the plot itself, maybe there is something I can do.

Comment: That error dialog is a bit strange, that shouldn't happen. To speed up compilation, you can put `\usetikzlibrary{external} \tikzexternalize` into your preamble, then the graph will be compiled into a separate pdf on the first run. On subsequent runs, only that pdf will be included, instead of having to recalculate the whole plot. If you want to change something about the plot, you'll have to put `\tikzset{external/remake next}` in front of the `\begin{tikzpicture}` to update the externalized pdf.