# How can I maintain the size of epslatex figures after embedding into a LaTeX documnet?

Tags: gnuplot, eps

I use the following commands to plot a figure in epslatex.

```
set terminal epslatex size 3.0in,2.25in font ',8'
set output 'filename.tex'
```

The `epslatex` terminal produces two files: `filename.tex` and `filename.eps`. As discussed in [Gnuplot epslatex terminal not showing axis text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58900/gnuplot-epslatex-terminal-not-showing-axis-text), I embed this tex file `filename.tex` into a latex document by:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
        \includegraphics{filename}
        \caption{simulation result}
        \label{f_sim}
\end{figure}
```

However, the figure size is much larger than `3.0in,2.25in`. How can I keep the figure size unchanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do always give *full* but minimal scripts and documents. The snippets you give aren't compileable. It are quite often those parts which aren't posted which make the problems.

Here a short example, which works fine:

A gnuplot script `filename.gp`:

```
set terminal epslatex size 3.0in,2.25in font ',8'
set output 'filename.tex'
plot x
```

And a document `main.tex` with the content

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \input{filename}
    \caption{simulation result}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Now run

```
gnuplot filename.gp
pdflatex main.tex
```

to get a document with a correctly sized image.